# POSTMAN - Check response header's value is no null

Tags: postman

I am not sure how I to check that the value for the header is not null.
I have a test to ensure the header is there:

```
pm.test("Check there is an header", function() {
   pm.response.to.have.header("random");
});
```

However, due to the value changing with every tag, I just want to make sure random is not null.

Answer (score 0):

OMG!
It was as simple as `pm.response.to.be.header("random").to.not.eql( null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.response.to.have.header("random");
pm.expect(pm.response.headers.get('random')).to.not.eql(null);
```